# view the pdf file in html page or browser but default pdf url is target to download

Tags: javascript, jquery

here the following pdf url by default targeted to download 
URL: https://u.godigit.com/q3nzx63

needed to view in html page or browser

Comment: Have a look at the PDF JS plugin: 1) https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/ , 2) https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js#online-demo , 3) https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

Comment: What have you tried so far ?? Show us what you have searched/tried

Comment: i tried using iframe but still downloading

Comment: we can use google docs api like this <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://u.godigit.com/q3nzx63&embedded=true"></iframe>

Comment: but i need without using third party api or services .

Comment: If you have access to the backend, make the server add response header ```Content-Disposition: inline``` and ```Content-Type: application/pdf```

Comment: @Kristian  i don't  server credential